# Showing Multiple Related list for the Same Object

Tags: visualforce, related-list

We have an requirement to show multiple related list of same child object. For e.g. On Account object, we would like to show two related list of Contact object.

One related list need to show contacts with record type "Employee" and another needs to show contacts with record type "Clients".

It would be very straight forward by adding an inline visualforce page.
But, our requirement is that we would like to implement it with out of box feature of Salesforce.

Please let let me know, if someone has achieved such functionalities by using out of box Salesforce feature.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can achieve it by doing following :

- Create two lookup of Account object (Parent object) on Contact (Child Object)
- On child object you can make these lookup visible based on record types.
- These two lookups on Contact object will show two related lists on Account object.

I hope with this you would be able to achieve two related list with out of box feature.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

After Spring 2023 release, you can use Dynamic Forms (on multiple standard and all custom objects) which can be activated with clicking on the "Upgrade to Dynamic Forms" button in Lightning Builder on Related List Component.

With Dynamic Forms activated, you can add as much related list of the same object and give them the specific name, visibility and filters (in your case, you filter by record types).

More about Dynamic Forms can be found on: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=release-notes.salesforce_release_notes.htm&type=5&release=244

Have in mind that Dynamic Forms have their limits ... more about this on: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.dynamic_forms_limitations.htm&language=en_US&type=5